# Symbol's value as variable is void: debian-emacs-flavor when running ispell on tex file

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, debian, latex

I keep getting this error when I try to run ispell. I'm not sure where the issue comes from but I recently updated (on Ubuntu 10.04) to the newest emacs 23.3 from 23.1. I just copied over emacs-goodies-el from the debian package maintainer to my site-lisp that I put in my home folder. It seems to run completely fine if I start off with files that weren't edited in the old version or create new files. If I open the tex files I was editing previously that throws it off. Then any file I try to open after has the same errors below. On my other computer with similar setup I have done the same thing with same .emacs and it has no issues. I can open these same tex files just fine. Is there somewhere some information like this is stored or suggestions on where to look. If I open a new file it says:

```
Enabling Flyspell mode gave an error
```

Then running M-x ispell gives:

```
not: Symbol's value as variable is void: debian-emacs-flavor
```

Here is the error. What is weird now flyspell/ispell runs fine in the file I was having issues before but if I create new files it doesn't seem to work. If I make new files not in tex mode I seem to have no issues. Also I should note that when I work on latex/tex I usually run `emacs -q --load ~\.emacstex`. I have a feeling maybe this variable is set in default.el (not sure on this)?? Here is the error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable debian-emacs-flavor)
  (member debian-emacs-flavor (quote (emacs20 emacs21)))
  (not (member debian-emacs-flavor (quote ...)))
  (if (not (member debian-emacs-flavor ...)) (delete-process ispell-process) (process-send-eof ispell-process) (if (eq ... ...) (ispell-accept-output 1)) (if (eq ... ...) (kill-process ispell-process)) (while (not ...) (if ... ... ...)))
  ispell-delete-ispell-process()
  (if ispell-async-processp (ispell-delete-ispell-process) (ispell-send-string "\n") (kill-buffer ispell-output-buffer) (kill-buffer ispell-session-buffer) (setq ispell-output-buffer nil ispell-session-buffer nil))
  (if (not (and ispell-process ...)) (or no-error (error "There is no ispell process running!")) (if ispell-async-processp (ispell-delete-ispell-process) (ispell-send-string "\n") (kill-buffer ispell-output-buffer) (kill-buffer ispell-session-buffer) (setq ispell-output-buffer nil ispell-session-buffer nil)) (setq ispell-process nil) (message "Ispell process killed") nil)
  ispell-kill-ispell(t)
  (if (and ispell-buffer-local-name (not ...)) (ispell-kill-ispell t))
  ispell-buffer-local-words()
  ispell-accept-buffer-local-defs()
  (if (not recheckp) (ispell-accept-buffer-local-defs))
  ispell-region(1 24)
  ispell-buffer()
  (if (and (boundp ...) transient-mark-mode (boundp ...) mark-active) (ispell-region (region-beginning) (region-end)) (ispell-buffer))
  ispell()
  call-interactively(ispell t nil)
  execute-extended-command(nil)
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
```

Comment: Do `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and then do `M-x ispell` again.  Emacs will give you a `*Backtrace*` buffer of the error.  Paste the contents of that `*Backtrace*` buffer so those of us who aren't getting your exact error can help you.

Comment: How exactly did you upgrade to 23.3?  Ubuntu 10.04 is still on 23.1 officially.  Did you create your own build?  Or install from a PPA?

Comment: @tripleee-Yeah I created my own build in my home directory. Then just copied over the emacs-goodies-el files. Added in my other custom files to the site-lisp folder. Using Tyler answer in my .emacstex file appears to make everything work fine. I have been meaning to create one .emacs file for all modes. I originally set it up I had different ones because when I ran emacs I only wanted it to remember windows and what not when I was using latex mode. having the windows reopen was nice. All other times typically  when opening a file. I didn't want all these tex windows to load.

Comment: @J Spen - mixing extensions packaged for one version of Emacs with another build is likely to cause you more problems. Using the packaged Emacs with extensions you've installed yourself is usually fine. But emacs-goodies assumes you've installed a 'Debianized' version of Emacs, which is no longer the case for you!

Comment: There are properly Debianized builds you can install, try the naquadah PPA http://emacs.naquadah.org/ (though they are probably already on emacs24)

Comment: @Tyler- Yeah, I figured mixing the packages was bad but thought it was easier than installing all of them myself at first. I realized I don't use most of them so I may just manually add the ones I need. I still think it is something to do with an auctex built from a non-debian version to the debian version. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @tripleee-I should have known there was a ppa for it just didn't search for it because for some reason I typically enjoy building myself and with other packages is easier to manage. I think it will be easier just to give that a go. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

`debian-emacs-flavor` is apparently a variable set by the [Debian package maintainers](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/debian-emacs-policy) It won't exist on other Emacs distributions, but I would assume from your error that something in the emacs-goodies.el requires it. Two solutions: the ugly hack would be to add the following to your .emacs to supply the variable.

```
 (defconst debian-emacs-flavor 'emacs23
   "A symbol representing the particular debian flavor of emacs running.
 Something like 'emacs20, 'xemacs20, etc.")
```

This may solve the immediate problem, while risking introducing new problems with other parts of the emacs-goodies.el package.

The better solution would be to not mix Ubuntu and Debian packages, and just install the packages you need from Ubuntu repositories or from the upstream source. More work, but less likely to cause similar conflicts in future.

Comment: these were all from the ubuntu repos. Then when I installed 23.3 I just copied them over from the 23.1 install. This is good info to know. If I start getting the error again I will look into that.

Comment: I don't understand what you did then. If emacs-goodies was in the repositories, why didn't you just install the official version? Why did you copy it over by hand? It sounds like you've got a mix of packaged and unpackaged (i.e., upstream) programs.

Answer (score 1):

The lack of a definition for the `debian-emacs-flavor` variable is almost certainly caused by your use of `emacs -q` when starting up.  The customary way to avoid loading unnecessary cruft is to make stuff in your `.emacs` conditional, perhaps like this;

```
(eval-after-load 'tex-mode '(load-file (expand-file-name "~/.emacstex")))
```

That way, those customizations will only be loaded when you actually open a file in TeX mode (or a derived mode ... I think).  You'd have to do something complementary to avoid loading unnecessary stuff from your `.emacs` when you do want to edit TeX files.  (Quitting and restarting Emacs is not recommended anyhow, as you lose kill ring history etc.)

See also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dictionaries-common/+bug/619015 for some additional background on how Flyspell is integrated with Ubuntu's Emacs.

**Edit**: Major refactoring upon closer reading of your questions.

Comment: @tripleee-I redid so now I just run emacs --load .emacstex for now but I still get the issue if I don't define the debian-emacs-flavor in the .emacstex. If I do then all seems to be fine. I am guessing something is conflicting with the auctex or reftex packages. I can't seen anything in the .emacsfile that would cause it to go haywire. That is an interesting thread above. I may try to grab the upstream files to see if that fixes the problem. At least I have a temporary solution.

Comment: @tripleee-Seems to only happen if I create a file in the same folder as where I run auctex or tex files are located. Haven't completely verified but appears to be the case.